# Blazemeter - How to make an asynchronous call in YAML?

Tags: asynchronous, yaml, performance-testing, blazemeter, taurus

So, I have 2 API's, one POST and one GET call. I send some json data in the POST request and it generates an `id` as response. Then I have to use the `id` to make a GET request. I am testing for large data, so I need to wait until the `id` has been generated.

Here is my YAML script-

```
---
execution:
- concurrency: 30
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 10m
  scenario: 5K_Export Excel
scenarios:
  5K_Export Excel:
    store-cache: false
    store-cookie: false
    use-dns-cache-mgr: false
    variables:
      calcEngineId: ${calcEngineId}
      url: ${url}
    data-sources:
      # path of .csv files for ${calcEngineId}, ${url} and ${bearerToken}
    requests:
      - label: Post Pivot Data
        url: ${url}/${calcEngineId}/exportPivotDataToExcel
        follow-redirects: true
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
          User-Agent: ApacheJMeter
          Authorization: Bearer ${bearerToken1}
        content-encoding: UTF-8
        think-time: 30s
        timeout: 2m
        extract-jsonpath:
          jobId: $.id
        body:
          # body of POST request
      - label: Export To Excel
        url: ${url}/${calcEngineId}/exportPivotDataToExcel/${jobId}
        follow-redirects: true
        method: GET
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/octet-stream
          User-Agent: ApacheJMeter
          Authorization: Bearer ${bearerToken1}
        content-encoding: UTF-8
        think-time: 1m
        timeout: 2m
```

I am extracting the `id` and storing it in a variable called `jobId` through this-

```
extract-jsonpath:
          jobId: $.id
```

And then I am using this `jobId` in the url of the GET request as seen above.

When I run this in blazemeter, the GET call shows Bad Request probably due to `jobId` not being generated yet while making the GET call.

I tried adding a `think-time` of 60s in between the POST and GET calls but it didn't work.

```
- label: Think for 1 Minute
        think-time: 60000
```

How do I achieve this? Is there any other way to make an async call in YAML?

I would also like to mention that it is working fine when I have a relatively small data in the body of the POST call. The problem arises when the data is large, lets say 10k-15k lines.

Answer (score 0):

In BlazeMeter's [Logs Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261977460881-Logs-Report#h_b67e50b6-4b3e-498f-8b6d-8261ee2fb23d) there should be [`error.jtl` file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/#Executor-specific-files)

It contains request and response data and [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) for failing samplers, so you can check what is being send and what is the response.

Additionally you can:

1. Create an [Assertion](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Assertions) to ensure that your POST request is doing what it supposed to be doing especially when it comes to "large" requests. If it fails - you will be able to see its details in `error.jtl` file
2. Amend [JMeter Test Log](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Test-Log) configuration so it would save everything, this way you will be able to debug your test.